# Bloquear edição forçada do input hidden

Tags: php, html5, ajax, formulário

Por exemplo, tenho um um sistema de estoque em PHP e nele a sessão editar quantidade do produto. Aqui temos um formulário para adicionar a quantidade. Nesse formulário tenho um campo hidden que pega o id do produto para dar o update na tabela produtos.

Eu pego este post e mando via ajax para um arquivo gestão php fazer a validação.

Duvida, se eu ir la no "inspecionar elemento" do navegador, mudar na mão o campo value do input hidden o php/codigo vai aceitar a inserção forçada de um campo que por ser hidden apenas deveria levar o valor para o post e não ser editado.

Tem alguma maneira de prevenir isto?

Comment: Sim, trabalhando no back-end para que o input hidden não faça parte da lógica de alteração dos dados

Comment: Trabalhe com `sessions`. Armazene os dados do carrinho em um array e quando receber essa request, você verifica se o produto está no carrinho.